# TinyMCE is not defined on WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I have a console error that says Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined and I really don't know how to solve that. It says that the error is in the javascript file below:

```js
(function() {
 
 "use strict";

       tinymce.PluginManager.add('wdm_mce_button', function( editor, url ) {
           editor.addButton('wdm_mce_button', {
                       text: 'Team',
                       icon: false,
                       onclick: function() {
                         // change the shortcode as per your requirement
                          editor.insertContent('[team_section]');
                      }
             });
                      editor.addButton('services', {
                       text: 'Services',
                       icon: false,
                       onclick: function() {
                         // change the shortcode as per your requirement
                          editor.insertContent('[services_section]');
                      }
             });
       });
})();
```

So the error should be in the "tinymce.PluginManager.add" line. I must mention that this code is running on wordpress and I use it to add some buttons in my classic editor. I'm waiting for some help please.

Thank you!

Comment: What action/hook are you calling this in?

Comment: Is just a javascript used to add extra buttons in the classic editor

Comment: Javascript doesn't exist on its own... you must have put it *somewhere*. Where are you calling it from?

Comment: This file is in a js folder and it's called with wp_enqueue in functions.php

Comment: Ok, so its in functions.php. Where exactly? Are you calling it from an appropriate action hook?